# why am I getting NameError on AlienInvasion.py

Tags: python, pygame

Output:

```
pygame 2.0.0 (SDL 2.0.12, python 3.8.6)
Hello from the pygame community. https://www.pygame.org/contribute.html
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\New User\Python Projects\Aliens Invasion Game\alien_invasion.py", line 5, in <module>
    class AlienInvasion:
  File "C:\Users\New User\Python Projects\Aliens Invasion Game\alien_invasion.py", line 26, in AlienInvasion
    ai = AlienInvasion()
NameError: name 'AlienInvasion' is not defined
```

```py
import sys

import pygame

class AlienInvasion:
    """Overall class to manage game assets and behaviour."""

    def __init__(self):
        """Initialize the game, and create game resources."""
        pygame.init()

        self.screen = pygame.display.set_mode((1200, 800))
        pygame.display.set_caption("Alien Invasion")

    def run_game(self):
        """Start the main loop for the game."""
        while True:
            for event in pygame.event.get():
                if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                    sys.exit()
#make the most recently drawn screen visible.
            pygame.display.flip()

    if __name__ == '__main__':
        #make a game instance and run the game.
        ai = AlienInvasion()
        ai.run_game()
```

Why am I getting `NameError` on `AlienInvasion.py`?

Answer (score 2):

The original code you posted has an indentation issue - your `if __name__ == '__main__'` block is indented, meaning it's actually considered to be within the scope of `class AlienInvasion`:

```
import ...

class AlienInvasion:

    def __init__(self):
        ...

    def run_game(self):
        ...

    # IMPORPERLY INDENTED:
    if __name__ == '__main__':
        #make a game instance and run the game.
        ai = AlienInvasion()
        ai.run_game()
```

Since you're trying to use `AlienInvasion` in the middle of its own definition, you'll therefore get something like this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<string>", line 16, in AlienInvasion
NameError: name 'AlienInvasion' is not defined
```

Thus, in order to fix the error, you have to fix your indentation, so that your `main` block is outside of `AlienInvasion`:

```
import sys

import pygame

class AlienInvasion:
    """Overall class to manage game assets and behaviour."""

    def __init__(self):
        """Initialize the game, and create game resources."""
        pygame.init()

        self.screen = pygame.display.set_mode((1200, 800))
        pygame.display.set_caption("Alien Invasion")

    def run_game(self):
        """Start the main loop for the game."""
        while True:
            for event in pygame.event.get():
                if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                    sys.exit()
            #make the most recently drawn screen visible.
            pygame.display.flip()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    #make a game instance and run the game.
    ai = AlienInvasion()
    ai.run_game()
```

Comment: got it, thanks for your help... should have known it!

Answer (score 1):

You should remove your main block from the definition of the `AlienInvasion` class.
Your `.py` file should look like this:

```
import sys

import pygame

class AlienInvasion:
    """Overall class to manage game assets and behaviour."""

    def __init__(self):
        """Initialize the game, and create game resources."""
        pygame.init()

        self.screen = pygame.display.set_mode((1200, 800))
        pygame.display.set_caption("Alien Invasion")

    def run_game(self):
        """Start the main loop for the game."""
        while True:
            for event in pygame.event.get():
                if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                    sys.exit()
            #make the most recently drawn screen visible.
            pygame.display.flip()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    #make a game instance and run the game.
    ai = AlienInvasion()
    ai.run_game()
```